# Flask Authentication with LDAP using flask_ldap3_login

Tags: python, flask, ldap, flask-login

I am trying to authenticate my Flask app with the Active Directory using `flask_ldap3_login`.  I have written the code to check the connection with active directory:

```
from flask_ldap3_login import LDAP3LoginManager

config = dict()

config['LDAP_HOST'] = 'my_ldap_host'
config['LDAP_BASE_DN'] = 'dc=internal,dc=com'
config['LDAP_USER_DN'] = 'ou=users'
config['LDAP_GROUP_DN'] = 'ou=groups'
config['LDAP_USER_RDN_ATTR'] = 'cn'
config['LDAP_USER_LOGIN_ATTR'] = 'dn'
config['LDAP_BIND_USER_DN'] = None
config['LDAP_BIND_USER_PASSWORD'] = None


ldap_manager = LDAP3LoginManager()
ldap_manager.init_config(config)


response = ldap_manager.authenticate('username', 'password')
print response.status
```

When I provide with my LDAP credentials it throws the error

```
   raise LDAPOperationResult(result=result['result'], description=result['description'], dn=result['dn'], message=result['message'], response_type=result['type'])
ldap3.core.exceptions.LDAPOperationsErrorResult: LDAPOperationsErrorResult - 1 - operationsError - None - 000004DC: LdapErr: DSID-0C0906E8, comment: In order to perform this operation a successful bind must be completed on the connection., data 0, v1db1  - searchResDone - None
```

Can someone tell me the proper way to authenticate the flask application with LDAP?

Comment: I'm facing the same issue.

Answer (score 2):

You need to provide login and password to access your LDAP:

```
app.config['LDAP_BIND_USER_DN'] = 'CN=someUser,CN=Users,DC=domain,DC=local'
app.config['LDAP_BIND_USER_PASSWORD'] = "secretpw"
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you get it to work?
Did you have these lines in your code? If you didn't, why?

`login_manager = LoginManager(app) # Flask-Login Manager`
`ldap_manager = LDAP3LoginManager(app) # Setup a LDAP3 Login Manager`